# list-style-item CSS is not applied to UL

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists

I can't get list-style-item to apply to my UL in chrome even though I'm setting `display` to `list-item` and suffixing with `!important`. I'm using Angular and bootstrap and am applying my CSS as the last `<link>` in the `<head>` - here's the HTML before Angular applies it's repeater:

```
<ul class="shipping-list">
    <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
        <select ng-model="todo.country">
            <option>Canada</option>
            <option>United Kingdom</option>
            <option>United States</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" ng-model="todo.text" ng-required="true">
        <i class="fa fa-times" ng-click="deleteTodo(todo)" alt="Remove"></i>
    </li>
    <li>
        <select ng-model="todoCountry">
            <option>Canada</option>
            <option>United Kingdom</option>
            <option>United States</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" ng-model="todoText"  size="30" placeholder="$shipping">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addTodo()">Add</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

HTML after Angular applies it's repeater - Providing for completeness although I'm pretty sure this is not related to Angular use:

```
<ul class="shipping-list">
  <!-- ngRepeat: todo in todos -->
  <li ng-repeat="todo in todos" class="ng-scope">
    <select ng-model="todo.country" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
      <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
      <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
      <option value="United States">United States</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" ng-model="todo.text" ng-required="true" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required" required="required">
    <i class="fa fa-times" ng-click="deleteTodo(todo)" alt="Remove"></i>
  </li><!-- end ngRepeat: todo in todos -->
  <li ng-repeat="todo in todos" class="ng-scope">
    ...
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
//Shipping list
ul.shipping-list {
  list-style-type: none !important;
  color: red;
  border: solid 1px red !important;
}
ul.shipping-list li {
  display:list-item !important;
  border: solid 1px red;    
}
ul.shipping-list input {
  color: red;
  background-color: cyan;  
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

The result is as follows - Note that list items still have bullets and there's no border on the UL:

[image: List Item style not applied]

Comment: Make a sample [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) on http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: because you use !important on li with list-item, so bullets comes back .You should not use so much !important without any wise reason.

Comment: None of the style attributes defined for `ul.shipping-list` get applied (neither `border`, nor `color` or `list-style-type`). Possible reason there are some CSS rules with greater specificity somewhere that overwrite those. You need to provide and **[SSCCE](http://sscce.org)**.

Comment: !important doesn't change the output, I've tried it both ways.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bFsHH/1/

Comment: The answer refers to an error that is not included in the code posted.

Comment: Updated question as noted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a C# style comment just before the UL CSS:

```
//Shipping list <= BAD COMMENT
ul.shipping-list { ... }
```

Removing the comment fixed the problem

```
ul.shipping-list { ... }
```